# In node imagemagick-native how to add callback method for convert method

Tags: node.js, imagemagick-convert

In below convert method i need to add callback method.How can i do that.

```
 var imagemagick = require('imagemagick-native');
 var srcData     = require('fs').readFileSync('./test/test.png'); 

 imagemagick.convert({
       srcData: srcData, 
       width: 100,
       height: 100,
       resizeStyle: "aspectfill",
       quality: 80,
      format: 'JPEG'
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `imagemagick-native`, method `convert` is synchronous, and does not require any callback to be defined.